# Ajax post data not showing when getting request in Laravel controller

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, request

This is the ajax that I made that send data from an array called `mdata`:

```
    var mdata={};
        mdata['evid']="4";
        console.log(mdata);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            headers: {
              'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
           
            url: "/DeleteKegiatan",
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            data: mdata,
       

     success: function(e) {
}
});
```

Controller:

```
public function destroy(Request $req){
        
        print_r($req->input('evid')); print_r($req['evid']);print_r("aa");   //it only return "aa"
        die();

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `$req->all();` to see all of the variables, as well as `$req->get('evid', 'no response');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `processData` and `contentType` in your ajax request, they are used primarily for FormData POSTs, which you are not doing.